# How to create simple bar chart application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-plot, bar-chart

I am new in iPhone Bar chart application, I didn't know, how to start this application?, I refer this link

> http://iphoneapplicationdevelopers.blogspot.in/2011/03/iphone-sdk-how-to-draw-bar-charts-using.html

but the Core-plot framework how to download and install, please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download core-plot from 
 http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Find the documentation here:
 
http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/index.html

You can find more examples and tutorials here:
 
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/PlotExamples

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) describes how to install core-plot for an iphone project.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to this link and read how to add core-plot in my applications..
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

Form this link , open your mac terminal and paste  your terminals

```
hg clone http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/ core-plot
```